# How do workspaces work in Aptana 3?

Tags: eclipse, aptana, aptana3

I'm new to programming and IDEs.  I never understood the concept of a workspace in Eclipse, and I don't understand it in Aptana.

With Eclipse I just put it into my web root. Not sure if that's the way to go?

Can someone explain what a workspace is and where it should go?  And if not in the web root, then how do I launch a PHP page from within the EDI?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Eclipse workspace is a directory where (generally) all of the files you are working on live and that stores all of the state (like preferences and such) for a single user of Eclipse. So when you create projects, they are located in the workspace. The workspace has some metadata files that control how Eclipses behaves for you.

Eclipse keeps a representation of the workspace internally, which means the workspace can get out of sync with the underlying files. To sync them up, do a right-click Refresh in the Package/Project Explorer.

Usually the workspace goes into some directory relative to your home directory, since it's private to each developer.

Comment: but for web projects with PHP it has to be in the servers directory

Comment: No, I don't think so, part of the web tooling in eclipse is that it publishes your web-related files to their destination for the server. The other thing you can do with the workspace is to link projects to other areas in the file system.

Comment: So I just installed and put my workspace outside of my web root. How do I now take the projects I'm working on launch them in the server?

Comment: When you create a project, you can specify a location on disk for your project that is in a directory visible by your web server. I just looked at the Aptana stuff and they seem to do it  differently than the Eclipse webtooling. [here is their doc](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Setting+up+an+external+web+server+to+preview+PHP+and+other+non-HTML+pages) for doing this.

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I said, creating the Web-Project in the Servers directory.

Comment: Actually you suggested creating the workspace there, and I'm (and Aptana) are suggesting creating projects in the workspace there, that's different). You want the workspace in a location that's not related to the webserver as it contains a bunch of state other than the files that are visible to the user.

Comment: Ok, so I got it to sort of work. The problem now is that it doesn't remember my "run as" configuration. I can't click CTRL-F11 like I used to in Eclipse. It complains that "The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches." What am I missing?

Comment: Go into Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Launching and select "Always lauch the previous..." (at the bottom)

Answer (score 0):

Workspaces are like folders where the project's files are.
When you have a local web server you could set the workspace to a new folder in the servers directory (or web root when the project should be in the main directory!) . If you want to add a new PHP-file in Aptana studio 3 just right click the workspace and select add new file (or sth. like that). After that you will be able to enter a file-name and it's gonna be saved in the workspace (folder). But of course you can also work without workspaces, just create the the PHP-File and edit it with Aptana.

Comment: If I created my workspace outside of the local web server, is there a way to work on it and deploy to the local web server?

Comment: It's possible to connect to an FTP-Server but on the same computer I don't know... It's better to create the workspace within the servers directory, as you don't have to copy the files.